# Trained Keras classification NN predictions output 'NaN'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm training a model using a dataset(4458, 172) where 2 columns show whenether a row is related to 2 of the classes. A single row of variables can be related to either of them, both at once or neither. The prediction should output two probabilities of the input data being related to the 2 classes.

Here's my code:

```
dataset.shape # (4458, 172)
X = dataset[:, 2:]
X.shape       # (4458, 170)
Y = dataset[:,0:2]
Y.shape       # (4458, 2)

scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X)
X_scale = scaler.transform(X)
X_scale

X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size = 0.4)
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size = 0.5)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(170, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (170,)),
    Dense(85, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(48, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(16, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(8, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=170, epochs=200,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)

X[0:1].shape   # (1, 170)
prediction = model.predict(X[0:1])
prediction
```

model.fit output on last few epochs:

```
Epoch 190/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 18us/step - loss: 0.0929 - accuracy: 0.9632 - val_loss: 0.1616 - val_accuracy: 0.9451
Epoch 191/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 18us/step - loss: 0.0848 - accuracy: 0.9671 - val_loss: 0.1917 - val_accuracy: 0.9333
Epoch 192/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 16us/step - loss: 0.0964 - accuracy: 0.9576 - val_loss: 0.1510 - val_accuracy: 0.9428
Epoch 193/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 18us/step - loss: 0.0959 - accuracy: 0.9662 - val_loss: 0.1576 - val_accuracy: 0.9400
Epoch 194/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 16us/step - loss: 0.0907 - accuracy: 0.9648 - val_loss: 0.1787 - val_accuracy: 0.9395
Epoch 195/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 16us/step - loss: 0.0812 - accuracy: 0.9680 - val_loss: 0.1503 - val_accuracy: 0.9479
Epoch 196/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 23us/step - loss: 0.0866 - accuracy: 0.9637 - val_loss: 0.1554 - val_accuracy: 0.9428
Epoch 197/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 17us/step - loss: 0.0939 - accuracy: 0.9605 - val_loss: 0.1512 - val_accuracy: 0.9445
Epoch 198/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 18us/step - loss: 0.0862 - accuracy: 0.9639 - val_loss: 0.1544 - val_accuracy: 0.9451
Epoch 199/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 18us/step - loss: 0.0849 - accuracy: 0.9673 - val_loss: 0.1601 - val_accuracy: 0.9428
Epoch 200/200
2674/2674 [==============================] - 0s 17us/step - loss: 0.0881 - accuracy: 0.9647 - val_loss: 0.1578 - val_accuracy: 0.9417
```

The model training seems to be going fine. Loss and accuracy data look believable enough through the epochs and model evaluation confirms high accuracy of the trained model. But when I try model prediction of a single row of data it presents me with `[[nan, nan]]` instead of desired values.

Looking for similar issues I found a few threads where people encountered NaN values in their loss and accuracy metrics. Changing the optimizer seemed to solve their trouble but it didn't help me. I checked my dataset for NaN and Inf values and it came out clean so this doesn't seem to be the cause.

I'm kinda stumped as the NN seems to be trained but refuses to give desired prediction values. How did it check itself during training then? Looking for help figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rustigator, This code is working fine when I tried replicating with the random dataset. Could you please describe about the dataset and how the labels values look like in the columns to further assist you in this issue? What is the output of `dataset.head(), X.head()` and `Y.head()`?